# Ruby / Chef: is there a way to refer to the resource 'name' and pass to a function?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, cookbook, recipe

Please see the following code, using the `log` resource in chef.

```
log 'Hello there' do
  level :info
  notifies :run, "log_to_chat('Hello there')"
end
```

Is there a way to refer to the resource `name` (in this case: 'Hello there') when I pass it to the function `log_to_chat`.

I imagine something like:

```
log 'Hello there' do
  level :info
  notifies :run, "log_to_chat(#{name})"
end
```

Adding my attempts for log_to_chat.

Attempt 1:

```
resource_name :log_to_chat

property :message, kind_of: String, name_property: true

chat_url = 'https://chat.server/abcdef'

action :run do
  execute do
    command "curl -m 5 -i -X POST -d \"payload={...}\" #{chat_url}"
    ignore_failure true
  end
end
```

Question: how to pass the `:message` parameter as a one liner from the `notifies` line?

```
notifies :run, "log_to_chat[message]", --pass :message how??--
```

Attempt 2:

```
module Chat
  def log_to_chat(message)
    chat_url = 'https://chat.server/abcdef'
    action :run do
      execute "curl" do
        command "curl -m 5 -i -X POST -d \"payload={...}\" #{chat_url}"
        ignore_failure true
      end
    end
  end
end
```

edit: attempt 2 didn't work since you can't use resources in a definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to the `name` variable. From [documentation](https://docs.chef.io/resource_log.html) you can read that "`name` is the name of the resource block". Keep in mind that you want to use the name of block (which is `Hello there` in your case) instead of resource name (which is `log` in the snippet from question)

Comment: Ok, thanks, is it then: `notifies :run, "log_to_chat(#{name})"` ?

Comment: well it depends on your code base, but `log_to_chat[#{name}]` is more likely . https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#notifies

Comment: Any chance to guide me on how to write the `log_to_chat` part, would that be a method in a module, or a custom resource, or how? It's basically a single `curl` command.

Comment: You can have for example a ruby block for that: https://docs.chef.io/resource_ruby_block.html.

Comment: You can use `declared_key` for a cleaner alternative: `notifies :run, declared_key`

https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/e6167aa5fe2decfe2395012c302360fc50054b9c/lib/chef/resource.rb#L1368

Answer (score 1):

If you want to notify resource `log_to_chat[some message]` (Attempt 1) you will have to explicitly declare it with action `:nothing` before `log 'Hello there'`. So it should look like this:

```
log_to_chat 'some message' do
  action :nothing
end

log 'Hello there' do
  level :info
  notifies :run, "log_to_chat[some message]"
end
```

Where it's valid code, it isn't best solution. To have 100% chef way solution, you should implement new [log resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_log.html) provider, by default it's `Chef::Provider::ChefLog`. You should implement 'Old School LWRP' provider mentioned [here](https://docs.chef.io/custom_resources_notes.html). In your new provider you can replace standard chef log resource functionality or just extend it by your curl calls or native `net/http` (or any other network gem) ruby calls (preferred).

Comment: Ok, thanks. How would I pass the `#{name}` to `log_to_chat[some message]` as a parameter or property from the `notifies...` line? (in this case, 'Hello there')

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible, I would extract it to variable before both resources.